# OpenGL 3.0: Access Violation exception caused by VBOs

Tags: vbo, opengl-3

I am updating a quite outdated OpenGL project. So I am trying to move from vertex arrays to VBOs, but I have an access violation exception that I cannot trace.

So I am using a VBO and an IBO that I generate in my class constructor:

```
if (glewIsSupported("GL_VERSION_3_0")) {
    glGenBuffers(2, bufferIds);
}
```

(glewInit() was already called)

The various rendering objects are defined as:

```
struct RenderBufferVertexElement
{
    NxVec3 position;
    NxVec3 normal;
    float texCoord[2];
};

// The rendering buffers
RenderBufferVertexElement* mVertexRenderBuffer;
NxU32* mIndexRenderBuffer;
// Buffer Objects
enum {
    VBO,
    IBO
};
GLuint bufferIds[2];
```

Then in my drawing function I do:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

// VBO
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferIds[VBO]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(mVertexRenderBuffer), mVertexRenderBuffer, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(RenderBufferVertexElement), BUFFER_OFFSET(offsetof(RenderBufferVertexElement,position)));
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(RenderBufferVertexElement), BUFFER_OFFSET( offsetof(RenderBufferVertexElement,normal) ));

// IBO
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferIds[IBO]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(mIndexRenderBuffer), mIndexRenderBuffer, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

textures.front()->setClientActive();
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(RenderBufferVertexElement), BUFFER_OFFSET(offsetof(RenderBufferVertexElement,texCoord)));

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures.front()->textureId);

[...]

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numElements, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glDisableClientState(...);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Everything worked fine with old style calls to glVertexPointer... but now my program crashes with an access violation exception. Any idea where that might come from?

Thanks

Comment: I also tried to call glBufferData() only during initialization but with no success.

Answer (score 2):

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

Don't call them. They are not needed and deprecated.
You just need to tell OpenGL how your data is organized with Attribute Sets.
Take a look at this Tutorial:
http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/

And also, do not use GLew. It causes glErrors() to appear because it uses a deprecated way to enumerate Extensions. 
Use Gl3w instead.